# How to get the all post_id where delete post? Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a function in a plugin and the function will delete the database row when the post move to the trash bin. However, I cannot get the post_id using `get_posts()`.

Here is my code:

```
function delete_condition($post)
{
    global $wpdb;

        $allposts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'category' => 0, 'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC', 'include' => array(),
        'exclude' => array(), 'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' =>'', 'post_type' => 'job',
        'suppress_filters' => true));

        foreach( $allposts as $postinfo ) {
            $wpdb->delete('rule', array('post_id' => $postinfo));
        }

}
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'delete_condition', 10, 1);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action hook you're using here, `wp_trash_post`, passes the $post_id to the function as a parameter.  See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/trash_post

It sounds like you want to delete all rows from one table that have the same post ID as the one being trashed.

I think you might want to write something like this:

```
function delete_condition( $post_id ) {
 global $wpdb;
 // Delete rows in the rule table which have the same post_id as this one
 if ( 'job' === get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
     $wpdb->delete('rule', array('post_id' => $post_id ) );
 }
}

add_action('wp_trash_post', 'delete_condition', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

$postinfo is the object. You want only the ID of post. So you should write $postinfo->ID. Replace your loop with the below -

```
foreach( $allposts as $postinfo ) {
            $postinfoID = $postinfo->ID;
            $wpdb->delete('rule', array('post_id' => $postinfoID));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
function delete_condition($post)
{
    global $wpdb;

        $allposts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'category' => 0, 'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC', 'include' => array(),
        'exclude' => array(), 'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' =>'', 'post_type' => 'job',
        'suppress_filters' => true));

        foreach( $allposts as $postinfo ) {
            $wpdb->delete('rule', array('post_id' => $postinfo));
        }

}
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'delete_condition', 10, 1);
?>
```